How can I check if key is part of an interface in typescript?
I have an interface [simplified]
export default interface FormListarAtendimentosDTO  {
    idArea?: number;
    idAssunto?: number;
    idMotivo?: number;
    order?: string;
    page?: number;
    pageSize?: number;
}

I have an instantiated query object with:
let form:FormListarAtendimentosDTO = { order: "ASC", page: 1, pageSize: 10 }
I have an updateQuery object with
let updateQuery = {queryParam: "idArea", value:"10"}
I want to check if obj.queryParam is a valid key on FormListarAtendimentosDTO, so I can update form to include the value on updateQuery. How do I do that?
if(keyExistsInInterface("idArea", FormListarAtendimentosDTO ))
{
    form.idArea = value
}

I tried to use
form.hasOwnProperty("idArea") and got false, because the value wasn't initialized
form.hasOwnProperty(updateQuery.queryParam) (same thing)
I tried
type K = keyof FormListarAtendimentosDTO
but i'm don't know how to use this information.
I tried
if("idArea" in formListarAtendimentosDTO)
didn't work either, always returned false

You can't do this. You need to keep track of the keys yourself; interfaces are erased along with the rest of the type system so there's nothing to access at runtime.  See linked q/a for more information.
